# kafka ktable - rocksdb access via java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Ive been reading about [ktables](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.java) this morning in hopes of implementing a rolling-window key-value store. I can see where the latest release of kafka seems to hint that this is possible but I'm more wondering about accessing the key-value data from 'outside' applications.

Say I implement a [kstreams](http://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple) application and it's consuming log data (or it's ilk) from a topic and merrily windowing, aggregating and producing to another topic. Now I want to look at this key-value data from some other process. The docs hint that the data is stored by [rocksdb](http://docs.confluent.io/2.1.0-alpha1/streams/architecture.html#state). Can I read this from 'outside' as a call to said db? Or is this data only available as a virtual construct to kstreams applications?

Comment: Note new and improved docs are out http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/ (you linked to the 2.1 alpha docs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`RocksDBStore`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/7edaa3dd89d1a7300a12e101e23f66459a9cc33d/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/internals/RocksDBStore.java) shows how to access the RocksDB store from Java. Basically:

```
RocksDB db = RocksDB.open(options, dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

and then you can `get()` and `put()` and `remove()`. You can configure where KafkaStreams stores the RocksDB state, so that's basically all you need to know to work with the store outside of the KafkaStreams.

With regard to windows—depending on how your windowing is configured, multiple `RocksDBStore` called [`Segment`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/7edaa3dd89d1a7300a12e101e23f66459a9cc33d/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/internals/RocksDBWindowStore.java)s are created are each window segment. You can access each of these stores as mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

Right now, there is no built-in support, but there are plans to expose the internal state (ie, `KTable` state) and make them queryable. See [KIP-67](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-67%3A+Queryable+state+for+Kafka+Streams) for more details.

Also, `KTable` state is written to a Kafka topic for fault-tolerance. Thus, you could also consume this topic and feed the data into an external database.

Comment: This seems to conflict with the other answer.

Comment: Well. Not really. The other answer describes a hand crafted (ie, non built-in) solution which requires some extra internal knowledge. Btw: it is highly recommended to only get() data from RocksDB. Put or remove might mess up your internal operator state.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about KIP-67

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax this is pretty interesting. I am working on a project that queries the distributed local state by sending queries by key to the targeted partition. This way I basically have a sharded DB wherein the shards are made possible by Kafka topic partitions and keyed local state. I am using the DSL, but basically only `#transform()`, so just one step above `#addProcessor()` and `#process()`. KIP-67 seems more targeted to the opacity that results from using the more complex elements of the DSL?

Comment: Yes. If you use the DSL, some state stores are created automatically, but hidden from the user. KIP-67 aims to make those stores available to the user. But also for the Processor API in which users create stores manually, KIP-67 will improve querying the stored due to "discovery service" and simple to use query-API (hiding all noisy RocksDB details).